# asyncio's call_soon fails where create_task doesn't

Tags: python-asyncio, python-3.7

```
import asyncio


def add_world_task():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    loop.call_soon(print_world)
    # asyncio.create_task(print_world())  # <-- This is a "fix",


async def print_hello():
    print("hello!")
    add_world_task()


async def print_world():
    print("world!")

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(print_hello())
```

The following code will run with a warning that the `print_world` coroutine was not run:

```
hello!
/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/events.py:88: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'print_world' was never awaited
  self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

Process finished with exit code 0
```

This makes sense to me, as per the docs for [`call_soon`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.call_soon), callbacks placed in `call_soon` will be run on the next iteration of the event loop. [`run_until_complete`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_until_complete) runs until the method is complete. Therefore, there won't be another iteration of the event loop once `print_hello` finished, and the coroutine `print_world` does not run.

What I don't understand is why `asyncio.create_task(print_world())` succeeds to run given `run_until_complete` definition. Once `print_hello` is finished, it seems the coroutine `print_world` still manages to be run in the event loop, against `run_until_complete`'s documentation?

Is this caused by `call_soon` placing the coroutine at the start of the event loop, `create_task` placing it at the back - and `run_until_complete` actually completing the current task *and* the remaining part of the event loop iteration?

(You may find it weird that I'm using the synchronous `add_world_task` and not `await print_world` directly. Unfortunately this is much like my real-world scenario. I have a synchronous method (a Django signal method) that needs to run an asynchronous method, while an event loop may already be running. It can do this by adding a coroutine to the running event loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `call_soon` and `create_task` schedule the callback at the end of the current iteration. Both get around to executing the callback because the event loop [fully completes each iteration](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/76553e5d2eae3e8a47406a6de4f354fe33ff370b/Lib/asyncio/base_events.py#L1869) before [examining whether to exit](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/76553e5d2eae3e8a47406a6de4f354fe33ff370b/Lib/asyncio/base_events.py#L597) due to `loop.stop()` having been called (which is how `run_until_complete()` is [implemented](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/76553e5d2eae3e8a47406a6de4f354fe33ff370b/Lib/asyncio/base_events.py#L191)).

`call_soon` doesn't work in your case for an entirely different reason: it is designed to run a non-async callback, i.e. an ordinary function which it just calls. You pass it a coroutine (async) function which is also a valid callable, but merely invoking that callable doesn't *do* anything, it just creates a coroutine object which you are supposed to either await or pass to `create_task`. Since `call_soon` expects the callback to operate by side effect, it drops this coroutine object on the floor which results in it never being executed and a warning displayed.

The correct way to schedule an async function to execute soon is precisely the way you fixed it, by passing its result `asyncio.create_task`.

Comment: Understood. Yes, I misread thinking that `call_soon` takes an async function to run on the next event loop iteration. Thanks.